# EntityState.Modified to update multiple records in single statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, change-tracking

To update single column of multiple records which has Unique key constrain, I tried with below code

```
foreach (var product in Products)
{
    product.Position= Position;

    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Below is the SQL being generated

```
update "XXMES"."TB_PRODUCT"
set "POSITION" = :p0
where ("PRODUCT_ID" = :p1)

-- :p0: '6' (Type = Decimal)

-- :p1: '6586632' (Type = Int64)
```

Even though I am updating all rows in single transaction, EF is generating SQL which updates one record at a time, which is causing below exception due to unique key constrain on the column, which is expected for generated sql as `Position` is unique. I am trying to figure out a way, SQL generates query to update all records at a time, so the constrain will not be violated. Please let me know if there is a workaround

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (RWMES.TB_TRIM_PATTERN_SET_POS_UK) violated
```

Comment: Is "PRICE" part of your key because the SQL statement looks fine. It's not updating the PRODUCT_ID which is the column that would normally be unique.

Comment: Actually Price is unique, updated word Price to `Position` to avoid confusion.